# Como funciona un procesador en cuanto a bits?

Tags: hardware, preprocesador, assembly

siempre he sabido que los procesadores son la mente del PC.
Entiendo que hay lenguajes que compilan a machine, otros son interpreados, MV ,etc.
Estos crean instrucciones para que el procesador las ejecute, entiendo que cada uno tiene su forma de trabajar.

Estos guardan datos en la memoria para trabajar etc etc.

Pero como funciona realmente esto de un Proceasdor de 8 bits(los antiguos), 16 bits, etc etc.
Estoy empezando en lo de la emulacion y me encontre con el "hola mundo" de la emulacion que es, CHIP-8,pero no comprendo como es que estos trabajar a 8 bits, tiene 4KB(4096 bits) de memoria,
pero no comprendo como hace su funcionalidad en base a 8 bits.

Comment: Tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada pues no me parece del todo adecuada al formato del sitio, checa [ask]

Comment: Te recomendaría mirar libros de Microprocesadores (yo estudié con Z-80 y era bastante complejo... no me quiero imaginar con los micros de ahora con X86, ARM u OpenRISC). Son bastante interesantes... y si en realidad quieres entender bien en profundidad los detalles tendrías que comenzar con un libro de Diseño Lógico o electrónica digital. No le veo el sentido a estudiar cuestiones de electrónica analógica (del transistor para abajo) porque ya sería demasiado bajo.... arrancando con las compuertas lógicas hacia arriba es más que suficiente material y complejidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendacion, una disculpa si no es el lugar para hacer la pregunta, pero he tenido este tema en la cabeza un rato y no me deja tranquilo jajaja.

Answer (score 1):

El del tamaño en bits normalmente se refiere al ancho (en bits) de los registros que tiene el microprocesador.... adicionalmente también hace referencia (hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento) del ancho de los bits que se usan para direccionar memoria.... con 8 bits solo debería tenerse acceso a 256 localidades de memoria, cierto? Claro.... el truco que se puede usar es utilizar instrucciones que fijan bits mas significativos que los 8 del bus de direcciones para poder moverse en, digamos, otras páginas de memoria. Esto incluso se puede ver en los micros X86 de 32 bits que usan PAE para poder acceder a mas de 4GBs de ram (que sería el límite para un bus de direcciones de 32 bits).

https://serverfault.com/questions/3342/how-does-a-32-bit-machine-support-more-than-4-gb-of-ram

Comment: Interesante que aun con PAE los procesos siguen restringidos a 4GBs de memoria.

Comment: Ok partiendo entonces de los 8 bits, si mi procesador tiene un ancho de bits de 8 esto quiere decir que trabaja con segmentos de este mismo valor? ni mas ni menos?

Comment: Sip.... el bus de direcciones ser'ia de 8 bits así que habría solo 256 localidades alcanzables "de una", habiendo la posibilidad de usar mas memoria con otros recursos provistos por el micro.

Answer (score 1):

Una rápida búsqueda en wikipedia arrojo que el chip 8 tiene un registro llamado **I** que es de 16-bits de ancho(65536 bytes de alcance entonces) que es usado para operaciones relacionadas con la memoria.

Y en x86(la arquitectura de los procesadores de Intel) en modo real(modo de 16-bits) se usan "registros de segmento" que son registros que guardan parte de la dirección en memoria dando así la posibilidad de acceder mas allá de los 64kB permitidos por los 16-bits.

Comment: Y PAE en x86 de 32 bits, como expliqué en mi respuesta.

Comment: Si y PAE en x86 para alcanzar 64GB de memoria, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se dice que un procesador es de tal o cual cantidad de bits se refiere a qué tamaño en bits tiene sus registros de propósito general. Una cosa es de qué tamaño tenga un procesador el acumulador y otra de qué tamaño es su bus de direcciones.

Un z-80, procesador de 8 bits, tenía un bus de direcciones de 16, y podía acceder a 65535 posiciones de memoria. Lo hacía usando para direccionar la memoria dos registros de 8 bits.

Los procesadores de intel de 16 bits, con un acumulador de 16 bits, tenían un bus de direcciones de 20 o hasta 24 bits en el 80286, usando el sistema de la segmentación para acceder a toda la memoria. En ella hay unos registros de segmento de 16 bits, que seleccionan un segmento, más los propósito general, que direccionan una posición de memoria dentro de ese segmento.

Los de 32 bits, con bus de direcciones de 32 bits, siguen usando ese sistema, con registros de segmento de 16 bits y de 32 para el offset de segmento. Pueden usar también la paginación, pero no superan los 4 gigas de direccionamiento.

Los de 64 bits tiene un bus de direcciones efectivo de 48. Funcionando a 32 bits usan  36 para acceder a la memoria usando la paginación, con lo que pueden direccionar 64 gigas. Funcionando a 64 prescinden de la segmentación, usando sólo la paginación.